# Session Concurrency not working with custom UserDetails

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Spring security maximum concurrent session setting is not working with custom `UserDetailsService` and custom `UserDetails` implementation. It allows login with same user from different machines.

But when I use custom `UserDetailsService` with Spring Security's `UserDetails` implementation `User`, it terminates first logged in session and logs in with the new session.

Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().and().httpBasic().and()
                    .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).and().and().userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Custom `UserDetailsService` with Spring Secutiy `User` implementation(**Working**):

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService
        implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        final User user = new User("user", "password", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
        return user;

}
```

Custom `UserDetailsService` with Custom `User` implementation(**Not Working**):

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService
        implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    final CustomUser user = new CustomUser();
    user.setUsername("user");
    user.setPassword("password");
    user.setAuthorities(Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER")));
    user.setAccountNonLocked(true);
    user.setAccountNonExpired(true);
    user.setCredentialsNonExpired(true);
    user.setEnabled(true);

    return user;

}
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Did you override `equals`and `hashCode` methods in your `CustomUser` class?

Comment: Just to point out, If you are using custom user `CustomUser` then you should have also implements `UserDetails` interface. Otherwise it would not work.

Comment: No. I just implemented interface methods.

Comment: I've implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods, now it's working. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring security 4 prevent concurrent login not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640847/spring-security-4-prevent-concurrent-login-not-working)